# How to search data of dynamic fields in sunpot solr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-solr

Created dynamic string field with below searchable do block in sunspot solr for rails app

```
dynamic_string :custom, stored: true do
  custom_fields.inject({}) do |hash, custom_field|
    hash.merge((custom_field.key) => custom_field.value)
  end
end
```

Solr save data inside document as

"custom:special_abc_ss": "abc"

How to query for this field on sunspot solr(i.e http://localhost:8982/solr/#/default/query) ?

Comment: Do you mean how you can use the Sunspot-library inside your RoR-app to query against the field, or how the syntax would look on the Solr side by itself?

Comment: Yes , in case of custom fields query parameters

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what you're looking for - in pure Solr/Lucene syntax, the query would be `custom\:special_abc_ss:abc` (you'll have to escape the colon, `:`, since it has special meaning in the query).